# Como ocupar toda la pantalla dependiendo de cada dispositivo?

Tags: flutter, dart

mi pregunta es si tengo una Columna en la que tengo diversos widgets, en este caso 3 containers, como puedo hacer que ocupen siempre le total de pixeles de la pantalla , es decir, cada container ocupara x pixeles variables con su padding pero que se reajusten para que siempre ocupen el total de "Heigh" que es lo que mas me interesa, para cualquier dispositivo.

He estado utilizando `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` para que de esta forma  `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.round() * 0.24,` poder segun el tamaño de cada dispositivo ir ajustando, pero no es efectivo.

Investigando descubri Expand o Expanded pero no me dio el resultado que queria , quizas por que no lo use apropiadamente.

**Columna:**

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                          .size
                                          .height
                                          .round() *
                                      0.03),
                              child: HighscoreTile(
                                  tipo: "Test", time: testHighscore)),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                          .size
                                          .height
                                          .round() *
                                      0.03),
                              child: HighscoreTile(
                                  tipo: "Mejor de 3", time: mejorde3Highscore)),
                          HighscoreTile(
                              tipo: "Mejor de 5", time: mejorde5Highscore),
                        ]),
```

**Cada container:**

```
class HighscoreTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String tipo;
  final double time;

  HighscoreTile({Key key, this.tipo, this.time}) : super(key: key);
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.round() * 0.24,
        child: Material(
          color: ThemeData.dark().primaryColor,
          elevation: 12.0,
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      tipo.toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      (time <= 0 || time == null)
                          ? "0.0"
                          : time.toString() + " secs",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Esto es actualmente lo que me pasa a cambiar a ciertos dispositivos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y el objectivo es este (ocupando toda la pantalla y tamaño de containers igual para todos pero variable segun pantalla para ocupar el total)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ese caso lo mejor es usar `Expanded` ,  así:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container1(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container2(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container3(),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Los 3 Containers o Widgets ocuparán la misma proporción en diferentes pantallas.

Comment: Me sirvio , pero podria decirme como hacer que esa columna empieze ocupar espacio a continuacion del app bar, por que a pesar de haberlo puesto con expanded ,el primer container es mas pequeño , creo que por que el app bar oculta parcialmente al container

Comment: El Scaffold tiene una propiedad `extendBodyBehindAppBar` , ponle true :)